# Suppose that $|a_n|<2$ and $|a_{n+2}−a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2−a_n^2|$, prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I have been trying to answer this question and manage to come up with this(not sure if it is correct). I would like to know if I can use $\epsilon > \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_2−a_1|$ in it? it seems a bit extreme, but I am not sure. Does my proof look ok?

I would really appreciate any insight/advice you can offer.

**Question**

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose that $|a_n|<2$ and  $|a_{n+2}−a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2−a_n^2|$ for all $n\leq1$.

Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

**My proof attempt**

$$\begin{align}
|a_{n+1}^2−a_n^2| &= |(a_{n+1}+a_n)(a_{n+1}−a_n)| \\
& = |a_{n+1}+a_n||a_{n+1}−a_n| \\
& \leq (|a_{n+1}|+|a_n|)|a_{n+1}−a_n| \\
& < 4|a_{n+1}−a_n|
\end{align}$$

thus $|a_{n+2}−a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a_{n+1}−a_n|$

thus $|a_{n+2}−a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_2−a_1|$ for $n \geq 1$

thus for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n,m \geq K$ and $\epsilon > \frac{1}{2^{K-1}}|a_2−a_1|$ s.t.

$d(a_n,a_m) \leq \frac{1}{2^{K-1}}|a_2−a_1| < \epsilon$

Thus the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence and it is convergent

**This concludes my proof attempt**

Comment: I don't understand how you jumped from showing an inequality involving $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$ to $x_n,x_m$. What are $x_m,x_n$?

Comment: @copper.hat oh I see the mistake, will correct it now. It was suppose to be $a_n$ and $a_m$

Comment: Looks fine to me.  I did an edit for a typo, and also removed some superfluous ()'s for legibility.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts thank you, I am really working hard on trying to understand real analysis

Comment: @Reuben You need to do some more estimation, as in $|a_m-a_n| \le |a_m-a_{m+1}|+ \cdots + |a_{n-1}-a_n|$.

Comment: @copper.hat you mean that the jumped to $d(a_n,a_m) \leq$ is not good and I must lead up to it using the estimation you provided?

Comment: @Reuben Correct, your estimate is incorrect.

Comment: @copper.hat my second attempt is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440140/suppose-that-a-n2-and-a-n2%e2%88%92a-n1-leq-frac18a-n12%e2%88%92a-n2